# Using tablespaces in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb, tablespace

Is there a way in which we can use the tablespace concept of Oracle in HSQLDB?

I have some Oracle scripts which uses tablespace concepts. I want to convert them such that they can be used with HSQLDB too.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way in which we can use the tablespace concept of Oracle in HSQLDB?*

No. HSQLDB does not support tablespaces nor does it have any similar concept.